# How do I align the arrays in order to fit each other?

Tags: c

I'm trying to start my new program. The program will ask for `n` employees from a company, then the `name`, `salary`and `sale of the month`. The output will show the previous information plus the `comission`, `net salary` and a `total` of each one of them.

For better understanding, this would be the output:

```
Name               Salary    Sale of the month           Comission    Net salary 
Elena Gomez       2000.00              1000.00              35.00       2035.00
Elle Johns        4000.00              1345.00              60.53       4060.53 
Stefan Cox        3200.00              4000.00             216.00       3416.00 
Total             9200.00              6345.00             311.53       9511.53
```

My problem it's that my code doesn't align the same as the previous output. I'm using `int` arrays and a `char` multidimensional array for now. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 6
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 50

void print_array(const char arr[][MAX_STRING_SIZE]);

int main ()
{
    int numemployees, cont=0;
    float salary[10], salnet[5], sale[5], comission[5][1], ind=0, total[1][50];
    char header[0], nom[5][40];

char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] =
    { "Name",
      "salary",
      "Sale of the month",
      "Comission",
      "Net salary"
    };

    printf("Enter # of employees to consult: \n");
    scanf("%d",&numemployees);

     for(int i=0; i<=numemployees; i++)
             {

                  printf("Enter employee's %d name : ",cont); // I'd like to show it from #1 not zero.
                  scanf("%s", nom[i]);

                  printf("Enter employee's %d salary : ",cont);
                  scanf("%f", &salary[i]);

                  printf("Enter sale of the month of the employee %d : ",cont);
                  scanf("%f", &sale[i]);

                  cont++;
                  system("cls");
            }

    print_array(arr); // function that shows the headers

    for(int i=0; i<=numemployees; i++)
    {

     printf("%s  %-25f   %-25f\n",nom[i], salary[i], sale[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the `print_array` function:

```
void print_array(const char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++)
    {
        printf("%-16s ", arr[i]);

        if (i == 5)
        {
            printf("%-16s \n", arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

My output shows something like this:

```
Name             salary           Sale of the month Comission        Net salary 
pedro  60.000000                    45.000000
```

I tried using  `printf` with `%-25f` but it doesn't fixed it. Please check it out if there's something missing or another idea to get the correct output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't use a width for the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```c
for(int i=0; i<=numemployees; i++)
    {

     printf("%s  %-25f   %-25f\n",nom[i], salary[i], sale[i]);

    }
```

You should indicate all columns width like this:

```c
for(int i=0; i<=numemployees; i++)
    {

     printf("%25s  %25f   %25f\n",nom[i], salary[i], sale[i]);

    }
```

If you put "-" before the number of characters x, you use x (in your case 25) chars to represent the info but you will get the left-aligned text.